# Does Espresso created activity always retain its references?

Tags: android, junit, android-espresso

I've observed a weird behaviour where the activity created in Espresso retains its references even after its recreated. I've ran into this problem when trying to rotate the activity and then check the adapter's count.

Here's the code that I used:

MainActivity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        adapter = new Adapter();
        Log.e("MAIN", "Adapter: " + adapter);
}
```

Test:

```
@Test
public void itemCountSavedOnRotate() {
        Log.e("TEST", "Adapter: " + mActivity.adapter);

        mActivity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        sleep(1000);

        Log.e("TEST", "Adapter: " + mActivity.adapter);

        mActivity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
        sleep(1000);

        Log.e("TEST", "Adapter: " + mActivity.adapter);
}
```

And the logcat that confirms the problem:

```
06-28 21:12:30.835  25871-25871/com.simas E/MAIN﹕ Adapter: com.simas.versatileviewpager.sample.MainActivity$1@25f54f7d
06-28 21:12:31.344  25871-25892/com.simas E/TEST﹕ Adapter: com.simas.versatileviewpager.sample.MainActivity$1@25f54f7d
06-28 21:12:31.485  25871-25871/com.simas E/MAIN﹕ Adapter: com.simas.versatileviewpager.sample.MainActivity$1@2969e070
06-28 21:12:32.429  25871-25892/com.simas E/TEST﹕ Adapter: com.simas.versatileviewpager.sample.MainActivity$1@25f54f7d
06-28 21:12:32.571  25871-25871/com.simas E/MAIN﹕ Adapter: com.simas.versatileviewpager.sample.MainActivity$1@2fae45a0
06-28 21:12:33.518  25871-25892/com.simas E/TEST﹕ Adapter: com.simas.versatileviewpager.sample.MainActivity$1@25f54f7d
```

Is it perhaps the default behaviour for Espresso?

Am I not supposed to be directly checking references but instead testing the UI? If so, what could be a possible alternative (tool) for such a test?

Comment: Can you show the code where you are assigning "mActivity"?  Thanks.

Comment: @AndroidGuy it's `mActivity = getActivity();` in `setUp()`.

Comment: What class are you extending?  Posting the entire test class would be helpful.  Thanks.

Comment: @AndroidGuy `ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<MainActivity>`.